# Predicting vector of counts

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, poisson-regression

I was wondering if there are any models that are similar to Poisson regression, but instead of having 1 count as the target, there is a vector of counts as the target.

For example:

Typical Poisson Regression: 
count ~ covariates

What I need: (count_1, count_2, ...count_n) ~ covariates

I haven't been able to find anything that does this as of yet.

Comment: You mean you have a multivariate target variable?  If the random components of each element of the target variable are independent, you can just run $n$ univariate Poisson regressions.  Is this the case?

Comment: Multivariate GLMs exist. Can you say more about the form of relationship (if any) among the DVs? How confident are you about the suitability of Poisson models?

Comment: @jbowman Each target is not independent. I do not know the exact relationship between the different elements of the target, but I suspect there are a variety of long-range dependencies that exist.

Comment: @Glen_b See above. The elements of the dependent variables are related to each other in some way. In an ideal scenario, I would use some sort of LSTM for this task, but there is a strong desire for a highly interpretable model in this case.

Comment: These are observations over time?

Comment: @Glen_b Observations over a region of space which is somewhat analogous to observations over time.

Comment: Ah. All this additional information - spatial data, expectation of long-dependence etc - should be in the question.

Comment: @Glen_b: Sorry! I tried to leave that information out because I didn't want to use a model that bakes in the possibility of long-range dependencies, but I should have mentioned it.

Comment: You can certainly state what you want to do or avoid doing in the question, though it may be a good idea to explain why.

Comment: @Glen_b: Right - The preference is to avoid models that are explicitly contain some level of sequential dependency, even something relatively simple like an HMM.

Comment: That's as a comment. You ought to edit your question.